# What is meant by words that R provides environment for statistical computing?

Tags: r

R is [described](https://www.r-project.org/about.html) as:

> R is a language and environment for statistical computing and graphics.

Why is R not just called language for statistical computing but environment for statistical computing?

I would like to very humbly understand the emphasis on *environment*.

Comment: Just read [this](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html)

Comment: @Christoph I think he's referring to a different kind of environment.

Answer (score 3):

R is called a language and environment for statistical computing because, unsurprisingly, it is both.

The environment refers to the fact that R is a programme that can perform statistical operations, just like SPSS (although that has a GUI), SAS, or Stata. You can perform ANOVA, linear regression, t-tests, or almost any other statistical method you would need.

The language refers to the fact that R is a functional and object-oriented programming language, which is in effect usable inside the environment. Anything you create is an object, while you can easily create new functions that perform new tasks.

So the overall package includes a statistical environment as well as the R programming language, which is commonly just referred to as 'R' overall.

From [What is R?](https://www.r-project.org/about.html):

> The term “environment” is intended to characterize it as a fully
>   planned and coherent system, rather than an incremental accretion of
>   very specific and inflexible tools, as is frequently the case with
>   other data analysis software.

Incidentally, @Christoph is right that there are also environments within R (like the global environment, or environments local to functions), but I don't think this is what this term refers to.

Answer (score 1):

Why the emphasis on environment? Officially stated [here](https://www.r-project.org/about.html):

> The term “environment” is intended to characterize it as a fully planned and coherent system, rather than an incremental accretion of very specific and inflexible tools, as is frequently the case with other data analysis software.

As stated in the quote: many other applications, some mentioned by @Phil, have incrementally grown in capability over a long period of time. That *incremental* addition of capabilities to software often leads to a quirky product that is frustrating to use.

By emphasizing environment, R is sending a message like: *We aren't that ancient program that has been patched for forty years and is frustrating to use. R is superior integrated software that you won't dread using.*

Side note: R-Studio is officially separate from R, but I consider R and R-Studio as one, and it is definitely an environment that just works.